# Processing 3 - Install Java Toolkit - mac 10.12.6

Tags: java, macos, processing, toolkit

I am working on a mac 10.12.6. In the processing 3 application, I am trying to install the java toolkit. The prompts appear as expected, but nothing seems to happen. What can I do?

update with more details

I am watching a lesson on how to make generative art, and the first step is to get processing 3 and sublime to listen to each other. So this toolkit needs to be installed.

[This is the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAZqh.png)

[the following prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PluUY.png)

I click yes to install for all users and put my password in. Nothing appears to happen and if you look back at the tools menu, it still says install. Also sublime cannot build, so I think that's another confirmation that is it not working.

Comment: What prompts appear? What are you expecting to happen? What happens instead? Questions like this are generally off-topic on Stack Overflow, but you'll have better luck if you provide screenshots and more specific details.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the confusion. Does this help?

Comment: @Caitlin What output do you get if you type: `processing-java` in Terminal ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Command line edition for Processing 0263 (Java Mode)

--help               Show this help text. Congratulations.

--sketch=<name>      Specify the sketch folder (required)
--output=<name>      Specify the output folder (optional and
                     cannot be the same as the sketch folder.)

........................

The --build, --run, --present, or --export must be the final parameter
passed to Processing. Arguments passed f .............. [I cut out some text because of the character limit]

Comment: That's great! that looks like you've got that installed and it works: you can now run/export Processing sketches easily from Terminal. Is this what you were trying to do ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Yes! I'm going to use sublime, but now I know it works. I was trying to run it through sublime and named the folder incorrectly, and I took that as meaning the java tool wasn't working.

Comment: In Sublime if you go to **Tools  > Build System > New Build System ...**, save that with the name of a sketch you want to run and for the `shell_cmd` value enter something like `{
 "shell_cmd": "processing-java --sketch=/ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/YOUR/SKETCH --run"
}` that should allow you to build that sketch from Sublime Text

Answer (score 0):

What worked eventually for me was:

```
brew cask install java
```